# Collecting data from Different VMs running different versions of Windows

Tags: windows, monitoring

We have a collection of VMs that need to be queried for specific information like dll versions for some applications. Currently this is done manually by logging into the machines and then collecting the data (also manually).

I could of course write scripts to automate the data collection, but what is the best way to do this from a single point across all VMs?

Also good to have would be the ability to collect some basic diagnostics around the VMs.

Note that these are regular Virtual Machine and not VMWare hosted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *regular* VMs? Java VMs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the VM aspect matters here at all.  You want to check some Windows files, so do as you would for any server, physical or not.

Not sure if it is the *best* way but SCCM may allow you to do a lot of this centrally.

A roll your own approach should also work, with a script that searches for files and versions, or perhaps WMI.